# Python error while cropping images: tile cannot extend outside image

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision, python-imaging-library, crop

I have a folder of JPG images having size 2048x1536. In every image date, time, temperature are given **in the top** and camera model name is given **at the end**. I want to crop only **upper part** and **lower part** of those image.

Image sample: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TefkFws5l2RBnI2iH22EI5vkje8JbeBk/view?usp=sharing

With the below code, I am getting error -**tile cannot extend outside image** **for any size I provide, for example (500,500,500,500) **. My target it (1500, 2000, 1500, 2000)

from PIL import Image
import os

```
#Create an Image Object from an Image
dir=r"C:\\Users\\Desktop\\crop1"
output_dir = r"C:\\Users\\Desktop\\crop2"
file_names = os.listdir(dir)

for file_name in file_names:
    file_path = dir +"\{}".format(file_name)
    im = Image.open(r"{}".format(file_path))
    cropped = im.crop((2000,1500,2000,1500))
    output_file= output_dir+"\{}".format(file_name)
    cropped.save(r"{}".format(output_file))
```

Comment: Appears you cannot specify a cropping area bigger than the image. You should also use `os.path` to manipulate paths instead of doing it manually (a more error-prone way).

Comment: Thank you. After getting knowledge, how those four tuple works, I solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

"(2000,1500,2000,1500)" is an empty box, which could explain why crop fails even if  the "tile cannot extend outside image" error isn't exactly fitting. The 4-tuple argument to crop has the meaning "(left, upper, right, lower)". Example from the [Image.crop() documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.crop):

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open("hopper.jpg")

# The crop method from the Image module takes four coordinates as input.
# The right can also be represented as (left+width)
# and lower can be represented as (upper+height).
(left, upper, right, lower) = (20, 20, 100, 100)

# Here the image "im" is cropped and assigned to new variable im_crop
im_crop = im.crop((left, upper, right, lower))
```

Comment: I understood by doing some study. Thank you so much for your link. Now the problem is solved. 
Image size was-2048x1536. I wanted to crop only upper and lower part. 
I provided the parameter (0,30,2048,1450)  to get my desire output.